# Summoning Fireball via a command on xbox one

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to summon an explosive fireball using a command block with the current code as:

> `/summon fireball ~ ~2 ~ {ExplosionPower:5,Direction:[0,0,0,0,0,0]}`

However it always says syntax error for all of it, I have tried different versions of the code but it will keep saying syntax error

Comment: PE has no NBT .

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a very slight problem in your command.
You didn't specify the motion of the fireball which I think may have caused the syntax error.

I suggest trying:

`/summon Fireball ~ ~1 ~ {Motion:[0.0,0.0,0.0],direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0],ExplosionPower:5}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfourtunatly this did not work but it may not be a problem with the command as its entirely possible that the Xbox One version does not allow you to summon fireballs or that they may have a different name. however, the syntax errors are at "Fireball" "Motion" "Direction" "ExplosionPower"